# Is it ok to delete observisions because of high unbalance panel data?

Tags: sampling, survival, panel-data, dataset, stata

I have data of around 100 companies/ 500 observations for 5 years. however, some of the companies in the data have unavailable observations for the whole 5 years. Some companies have only 3, 4 or 2 years. Is it ok to delete companies with no available data for two years and more? if yes, is there any reference that can support that?

Some of the tests in Stata cannot be performed for high unbalance data. particularly, cross-sectional dependence.

Comment: Is there any substantive reason why they are missing? What proportion are missing?

Comment: Yes, some companies were listed/delisted from the market during the 5 year period which make it impossible to get their data. these companies are less than 6%

Comment: When you say "okay" it can mean a lot of things.  You can have my permission, if you like.  That is nearly the opposite of saying "proper handling of math/stats says you may" because more information is required.  What process are you trying to perform on the information; what is the output; and what type of decision is it supposed to inform?  You don't have to get gory, but you could give enough class/category/general-direction details help inform a mathematically useful answer.

Comment: I am running panel data fixed effect regression for an article. Do you have a support for your permission or just speculation ?

Comment: If some companies were delisted then there must have been a reason for that and so just dropping them from the model is dropping companies which may differ in some important way. So i would be cautious about dropping them.

Comment: what about the inability to do the diagnostic  tests because of the high unbalance data. some companies listed only 1 or 2 years in the market

Comment: This is a loaded question. It seems that you want approval for what you are inclined to do any way. But (1) there's information that you are proposing to discard and unless you know that companies without full data resemble those with, there is a bias in discarding (2) any requirements of diagnostic tests shouldn't be the pivot on which a project swings; what is the main goal here? (3) you should seek approval from peers in your field; an internet forum can only be a Delphic oracle.

Comment: So is ok to have high unbalanced data? how to solve that?